# How to draw this tree of extensive game model?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

How is it possible to draw this figure?

[image]

There are some posts on how to draw a tree of an extensive game model, but I don't know how to modify them such that the following figure is produced.

[Nth Problem with TikZ and Extensive Form Games](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505169/nth-problem-with-tikz-and-extensive-form-games)
[Game theory trees, solid node size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482040/game-theory-trees-solid-node-size)

Comment: Please search about the `tree` llibrary. You may find help to begin with. Then edit your post with your MWE and your questions. Sure you will find someone to help you improve it. But asking for such a complex graph from scratch doesn't guarantee any answer here ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    
\begin{document}
     
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, node distance=3cm,on grid,
    Rec/.style = {
        draw, 
        minimum size = 1cm,
        outer sep=0},
    Circ/.style= {
        draw,
        circle,
        minimum size=1cm}]
 % Rectangles and circle
 \node[Rec,fill=gray] (rec1) {}; 
 \node[Rec,right=of rec1] (rec2) {};
 \node[Circ,right=of rec2] (circle) {};
 \node[Rec,above right=2cm and 3cm of circle] (rec3) {};
 \node[Rec,below right=2cm and 3cm of circle] (rec4) {};

    
% Directed lines
    \draw[-latex] (rec1) -- (rec2) edge node[above left](Nbuy){Buy}(circle);
    \draw[-latex] (circle) |- (rec3) node[pos=0.71,above]{Match}node[pos=0.71,below]{$m$}   (circle) |- (rec4) node[pos=0.71,below]{Mismatch}node[pos=0.71,above]{$1-m$} ; 
      
    \draw (rec3) |- ++(2,1) node[pos=0.71,above]{Keep} node[right]{$v-P$} (rec3) |- ++(2,-1)node[pos=0.75,below]{Return}  node[right]{$v-h$};

\draw (rec4) |- ++(2,1) node[pos=0.71,above]{Keep}  node[right]{$s-P$}(rec4) |- ++(2,-1)node[pos=0.75,below]{Return} node[right]{$-h$};
  
\draw (rec2) |- ++(8,-4) coordinate(Nnbuy)node[right]{$0$} ;
\node[above] at (Nbuy|-Nnbuy) {Don't buy} ;

 \node[below right,align=left,inner xsep=0,inner ysep=5pt]at (rec1.south west){Retailer \\ announces \\ $P$ and $T$};
 % Red dashed lines
 \draw[dashed,red] (2,4) -- (2,-5)(5,4) -- (5,-5)(10.75,4) -- (10.75,-5);
 
 % Top and bottom labels
 \node at (0.75,-4.75){\textbf{Retailer}};
 \node at (3.5,-4.75){\textbf{Consumer}};
 \node at (7.875,-4.75){\textbf{Consumer}};
 \node at (0.75,3.75){\textbf{Stage I}};
 \node at (3.5,3.75){\textbf{Stage II}};
 \node at (7.875,3.75){\textbf{Stage III}};
 \node at (11.5,3.75){\textbf{Utility}};
\end{tikzpicture}
 

\end{document}
```

Which yields the following result:
[image]

You can check this [tutorial about drawing block diagrams](https://latexdraw.com/block-diagram-in-latex-step-by-step-tikz-tutorial/) .

Comment: Thank you so much. It is great

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Dear @LaTeXdraw-com, Could you please let me know how it is possible to fix the position of text at the beginning of the arrow? For example, I removed the box after "Match" and extended the line, and then, the word "Match" moved and it is not aligend with "Mismatch". Thanks
One more thing, why are some right arrow and some lines?

Answer (score 3):

A solution that uses `child` nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14159cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [grow=right, scale=1.,font=\normalsize,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
    edge from parent/.style={draw,-{Stealth[scale=2]}},
    level distance=3cm,
    sibling distance=3cm,
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
    auto,transform shape,
    on grid]
    
    \tikzset{every node/.style={rectangle,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,draw}}
    \tikzset{edgenode/.style={draw=none,minimum height=0pt,rectangle,inner sep=3pt,pos=.75}}
    \tikzset{legend/.style={draw=none,minimum height=0pt,rectangle,inner sep=3pt}}
    
    \node[fill=gray](retailer) {}
        child { node (consumer){} 
            child { node[circle,fill=white] { }
                child { node {}
                    child { node[draw=none] {$-h$}
                    edge from parent node[edgenode,below] {Return}}
                    child { node[draw=none] {$s-P$}
                    edge from parent node[edgenode,above] {Keep}}
                edge from parent node[edgenode,below] {Mismatch} node[edgenode,above] {$1-m$}}
                child { node {}
                    child { node[draw=none] {$\nu c-h$}
                    edge from parent node[edgenode,below] {Return}}
                    child { node[draw=none] {$\nu-P$}
                    edge from parent node[edgenode,above] {Keep}}
                edge from parent node[edgenode,above] {Match} node[edgenode,below] {$m$}}           
            edge from parent node[edgenode,above] {Buy}}
        };
    
    \draw[edge from parent] (consumer) --++ (0,-4) --++ (8.5,0) node[edgenode,pos=.12,above] {Don't buy} node[anchor=west,draw=none,at end] {0};
    \draw[dashed]   (2,4) --++ (0,-9)
                    (5,4) --++ (0,-9)
                    (11,4) --++ (0,-9);
    \node[legend] at (0,-4.5) {Retailer};
    \node[legend] at (3.5,-4.5) {Consumer};
    \node[legend] at (8,-4.5) {Consumer};
    \node[legend] at (0,3.5) {Stage I};
    \node[legend] at (3.5,3.5) {Stage II};
    \node[legend] at (8,3.5) {Stage III};
    \node[legend] at (12,3.5) {Utility};
    \node[legend,text width=2cm,align=center] at (0,-1.3) {Retailer announces P and T};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**
I edit my post without deleting the first version. Here's an improved version without the flaws of the first rapid script.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14159mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [line width=.5pt,
    grow=right, scale=1.,font=\normalsize,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
    edge from parent/.style={draw,-{Stealth[scale=1.5]}},
    level distance=3cm,
    sibling distance=3cm,
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm},
    auto,transform shape,
    on grid]
    
    \tikzset{every node/.style={rectangle,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,draw}}
    \tikzset{edgenode/.style={draw=none,minimum height=0pt,rectangle,inner sep=3pt,pos=.75}}
    \tikzset{legend/.style={draw=none,minimum height=0pt,rectangle,inner sep=3pt}}
    
    \node[fill=gray](retailer) {}
        child { node (consumer){} 
            %
            child { node[circle] { }
            %
                child { node {}
                    %
                    child { node[draw=none] {$-h$}
                    edge from parent[-] node[edgenode,below] {Return}}
                    %
                    child { node[draw=none] {$s-P$}
                    edge from parent[-] node[edgenode,above] {Keep}}
                    %
                edge from parent node[edgenode,below] {Mismatch} node[edgenode,above] {$1-m$}}
                child { node {}
                    %
                    child { node[draw=none] {$\nu c-h$}
                    edge from parent[-] node[edgenode,below] {Return}}
                    %
                    child { node[draw=none] {$\nu-P$}
                    edge from parent[-] node[edgenode,above] {Keep}}
                    %
                edge from parent node[edgenode,above] {Match} node[edgenode,below] {$m$}}                   %
            edge from parent node[edgenode,above] {Buy}}
        };
    
    \draw (consumer) |- (11.5,-4) node[edgenode,pos=.56,above] {Don't buy} node[anchor=west,draw=none,at end] {0};
    
    \draw[dashed]   (2,4) --++ (0,-9)
                    (5,4) --++ (0,-9)
                    (11,4) --++ (0,-9);

    \node[legend] at (0,-4.5) {Retailer};
    \node[legend] at (3.5,-4.5) {Consumer};
    \node[legend] at (8,-4.5) {Consumer};
    \node[legend] at (0,3.5) {Stage I};
    \node[legend] at (3.5,3.5) {Stage II};
    \node[legend] at (8,3.5) {Stage III};
    \node[legend] at (12,3.5) {Utility};
    \node[below = 1.2cm of retailer,legend,text width=2cm,align=center] {Retailer announces P and T};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: v2]

Comment: Just edited my post to add a V2.

Answer (score 3):

This is my try of drawing the figure using the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]

\setistgrowdirection'{east}
\setistmathTF001
\setxtarrowtips{latex}[very thick]

\setistNewNodeStyle{init}[rectangle,fill=gray]{1cm}
\setistNewNodeStyle{rect}[rectangle]{1cm}
\setistNewNodeStyle{circ}{1cm}

\tikzset{RR/.style={edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)--(\tikzchildnode.west)}}} % (added)

\xtdistance{25mm}{30mm}
\istroot(0)[init]<[xshift=3mm]-90>{\makecell[l]{Retailer\\announces\\$P$ and $T$}}
  \istb<RR>[->-=.75] 
  \endist
\istrooto(1)(0-1)[rect]
  \istb<grow=0,RR>[->-=.75]{Buy}[above,pos=.3] 
  \istb<sibling distance=60mm,level distance=65mm>{Don't buy}[above,pos=.57]{0}
  \endist
\xtdistance{25mm}{30mm}
\istrooto(2)(1-1)[circ]
  \istB[->-=.93]{Match}[above,pos=.72]{$m$}[below,pos=.72]
  \istB[->-=.93]{Mismatch}[below,pos=.72]{$1-m$}[above,pos=.72]
  \endist
\xtdistance{15mm}{15mm}
\istrooto(3a)(2-1)[rect]
  \istb{Keep}[above,pos=.75]{v-P}
  \istb{Return}[below,pos=.75]{vc-h}
  \endist
\istrooto(3b)(2-2)[rect]
  \istb{Keep}[above,pos=.75]{s-P}
  \istb{Return}[below,pos=.75]{-h}
  \endist

\xtTimeLineV[dashed]([xshift=-7mm]1){3.5}{-4}{Stage I}[left=5mm]
\xtTimeLineV[dashed]([xshift=-7mm]2){3.5}{-4}{Stage II}[left=5mm]
\xtTimeLineV[dashed]([xshift=-1.5mm]3a-1){3.5}{-4}{Stage III}[left=15mm]
\xtTimeLineV[draw=none]([xshift=-1.5mm]3a-1){3.5}{-4}{\underline{Utility}}[right=2mm]
\xtTimeLineV'[draw=none]([xshift=-7mm]1){3.5}{-4}{Retailer}[left=5mm]
\xtTimeLineV'[draw=none]([xshift=-7mm]2){3.5}{-4}{Consumer}[left=5mm]
\xtTimeLineV'[draw=none]([xshift=-1.5mm]3a-1){3.5}{-4}{Consumer}[left=15mm]

\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```